# Terrain generating AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to do a terrain by placing some random squares on the stage but I can't do it , here is my code.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;


var i:Number;
var h:Number = 0;
var black:Sprite = new Sprite;


for (i = 0; i < 600; i++)
{
    if (randon <= 0.5)
    {
        i += 40;
        black.graphics.beginFill(000000);
        black.graphics.drawRect(i,h,40,40);
        black.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(black);
    }

    if (randon>=0.5)
    {
        i +=  40;
    }
}


var randon:Number;
randon = Math.random();
```

Comment: I don't see `h` defined anywhere...

Comment: anyway, when i define it, the value of randon it says it is NaN

Comment: put "randon" above the for loop..

Comment: because you define random after the loop

Comment: lol, thank you, sorry for that dumb error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var h:Number=0;
var black:Sprite = new Sprite() ; // missing constructor
addChild(black);

for (var i:int=0; i<600; i+=40)  // can do definition in here - int is preferred
{
    if (Math.random()<=0.5) // inline
    {
        black.graphics.beginFill(000000);
        black.graphics.drawRect(i,h,40,40);
        black.graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```

Comment: small addition: "i += 40" isn't needed if it will be the same in both cases. just use "for (var i:int=0; i<600; i+=40)"

Comment: good point, also there is no need to keep `addChild`ing - updated answer